# How to access a currently open browsers URL's with python

Tags: python, google-chrome, url, browser

I'm trying to write a python executable that runs in the background and records the amount of time I spend on facebook. This is one of my first projects in software development. The problem is, I haven't found a way to access the chrome browser and look at what URL's are open.

I've used selenium webdriver, but it seems to only be able to open up new tabs.
I've found some kind of google extension called google tabs api, but i'm not entirely sure if it even is a library I can import into python or if it's even meant for python.

Comment: I've figured out a workaround. Using a screen capture, you can identify the facebook logo and effectively determine that facebook is open in that manner. I believe Google does not give you access to open tabs due to privacy and security reasons.